# 8085 - binary equivalent of MOV and it's corresponding timing diagram

Tags: 8085

I've got two questions here:

**#1**

The MOV A,B is said to be a one byte instruction, where B = 000 and A = 111, then MOV should be equal to 00, but, The binary representation of the BC R<sup>p</sup> is 00. So, I'm getting confused as to how it is a one byte instruction.

**#2**
The MVI instruction involves only registers and yet it required a memory read operation:

[image]

but, MOV instruction ALSO involves only registers and yet it doesn't require a memory read, WHY?

[image]

Comment: Nitpick: it would help to state (in the question's title, or in the exposition) that you mean 8085 specifically. It's only in the tags currently.

Answer (score 1):

> The MVI instruction involves only registers and yet it required a memory read

This is a two byte instruction, where the second byte is directly ternsferred into the destination register. Thus two reads required: Opcode and value.

> The MOV A,B is said to be a one byte instruction

MOV does not accept register pairs, its opcode is two **bits** and the 2 operands are three bits each: One eight bit byte instruction.

> MOV should be equal to 00

No, the encoding of `MOV A,B` is `0170` in octal or `0x78` in hex.

Comment: Considering how an opcode is formed: A=001 and B=111, opcode forming tells that these should be tacked up as: 001111 and there are two bits remaining so that leaves for 4 values all taken by register pairs: HL, BC and DE, how come the hex: 0X78 formed?

Comment: Nope. Instruction format for MOV  in binary is 01xxxyyy where x and y are the three operand bits each.

Comment: You mean that for one byte instructions these are unique instructions, not following some general rule?

Comment: @BeshalJaenal The instruction is decoded in T4. If it turns out that this decoding determines that another byte (immediate value, for example) is required, then 3 more cycles (another state) are added to get that added byte.  An STA will require T1-T4 for the first byte, then three more states (each with T1-T3) for the remaining two reads plus one write. I'm not sure what's confusing for you.

Comment: Ok, I need to know how the MOV A,B is formulated in binary.